# Making a sauce with mascarpone cheese

Tags: sauce, culinary-uses, mascarpone

I have some mascarpone cheese left. May I use it to make a sauce?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add Mascapone Cheese to a plain italian tomato sauce. The sauce can take on quite a different feel to it from the normal pasta sauce which can make a nice change.

Answer (score 2):

This is a recipe for a quick "tiramisù". It can be used to serve cookies, or fruits.
It requires mascarpone cheese, 2 eggs, and cocoa powder (optional).

- Whip the egg white.
- Incorporate the mascarpone cheese into the yoke and mix.
- Incorporate the egg white, and mix.
- Add cocoa powder.

Leave in refrigerator before to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will melt similarly to cream cheese and can be used in sauces, or to enrich either polenta or risotto.

Answer (score 1):

It should work well as a sauce.
You can also use it to make a sweet sauce, as it has just the right balance of fat and flavour for dessert.

Mix it with peaches or blackberries, along with a reduction of some of their juice.
Will go well on a cheesecake or tart, or as a more refreshing replacement for custard on a crumble.

Answer (score 1):

Mascarpone works well for making a sauce. I've found it combines nicely with sweet chilli dipping sauce.

It is also eminently suitable as a filling for a [chicken kiev](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicken_Kiev) style dish.